# How can I tokenize a c-style string from a file without making a copy?

Tags: c++, string, performance

Let's say I have a constant c-style string say

```
const char* msg = "fred,jim,345,7665";
```

I'd like to tokenize this and read out the individual fields but for performance reasons I don't want to make a copy. How can I do this?

Obviously strtok takes a non-constant pointer and boost::tokenizer is an option but I am unsure what is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: What results do you expect? you must either copy it or mutate it to make each token null-terminated.

Comment: I'm okay with copying the individual fields out (ie. my example can become std::string, std::string, int, int) but I would like to avoid having to make an initial copy before I extract those fields.

Comment: In short, you want lazy-tokenization

Comment: Yes that sounds fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inevitably you will require *some* copy of the string, even if it is a substring being copied.

If you have a strtok_r function, you can use that, but it will still require a mutable string to do its work. Beware, however, as not all systems provide the function (e.g. Windows), which is why I've provided an implementation here. It works by requiring an additional parameter: a pointer to a C string to save the address of the next match. This allows for it to be more reentrant (thread-safe) in theory. However, you'll still be mutating the value. You could modify it to suit your needs if you like, perhaps copying N bytes into a destination buffer and null-terminating that buffer to avoid the need to modify the source string.

```
/*
   Usage:
     char *tok;
     char *savep;
     tok = mystrtok_r (somestr, ",", &savep);
     while (NULL != tok)
       {
         /* Do something with `tok'.  */
         tok = mystrtok_r (NULL, ",", &savep);
       }
*/
char *
mystrtok_r (char *str, const char *delims, char **nextp)
{
  if (str == NULL)
    str = *nextp;
  str += strspn (str, delims);
  *nextp = str + strcspn (str, delims);
  **nextp = 0;
  if (*str == 0)
    return NULL;
  ++*nextp;
  return str;
}
```

Comment: I love the arguments. How the source is a **  that is just clever.

Comment: Two things: 1) **nextp = 0; is altering the (supposedly constant) source string, and 2) Doesn't this fail to provide the final token?  *str = 0 will always be true for the last token (when strcspn(str,delims); returns zero)

Comment: 1) This function is designed for thread safety; no static variables, see? But as I claimed, it still requires a mutable string. 2) *str = 0 will be true when there are no more tokens, meaning you're at the end of the original string. str is the token returned, so if you're at the end of the string, it makes sense to return NULL. Run regular strtok on an "empty" string (one with an explicit '\0' in front) and tell me the behaviour differs. When a null terminator is reached, it is the end of the string. How can you find more tokens using a remaining string of 0 chars in length?

Comment: Yep, I was confused.  You could move your exit condition up two lines and save a minor amount of effort.  You could remove the requirement for a mutable input by also returning the length computed using strcspn.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're going to use it.
If you want to get the next token, and then the next (like an iteration over the string, then you only really need to copy the current token into memory.

```
long strtok2( char *strDest, const char *strSrc, const char cTok, long lOffset, long lMax)
{
  if(lMax > 0)
  {
    strSrc += lOffset;
    char * start = strDest;
    while(--lMax && *strSrc != cTok && (*strDest++ = * strSrc++) );
    *strDest = 0; //for when the token was found, not the null.
    return strDest - start - 1; //the length of the token
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I snagged a simple strcpy from http://vijayinterviewquestions.blogspot.com.au/2007/07/implement-strcpy-function.html

```
const char* msg = "fred,jim,345,7665";
char * buffer[20];
long offset = 0;
while(length = strtok2(buffer, msg, ',', offset, 20))
{
  cout << buffer;
  offset += (length+1);
}
```

Comment: Looks like that works. The only thing I would change is to return the end of strSrc (the last character processed in strSrc + 1) rather than the address in strDest. This way I can continue to process tokens by passing in that pointer.

Comment: I'd got with the long instead of the start of the next.  It would be more intuitive to others using the function. You could add it to the offset for the next token.  (well it + 1)

Comment: additionally if you return the length you could stop when it returned zero.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without a little more detail it's hard to know exactly what you want.  I'll guess you are parsing delimited items where consecutive delimiters should be treated as zero length tokens (which is usually correct for comma separated elements).  I'm also assuming a blank line counts as a single zero length token.  This is how I'd approach it:

```
const char *token_begin = msg;
int length;

for(;;)
{
   length = 0;
   while(!isDelimiter(token_begin[length]))    //< must include \0 as delimiter
      ++length;

   //..do something here with token.  token is at: token_begin[0..length)

   if ( token_begin[length] != 0 )
      token_begin = &token_begin[length+1];    //skip beyond non-null delimiter
   else
      break;                                   //token null terminated.  exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to store the tokens somewhere then a copy will be necessary in any case and `strtok` does this nicely by using the string a placing `null` terminating character inside it.

The only other option I see to avoid copying it is a lexer which reads the string and through a state machine produces tokens by scanning the string and storing the partial results in a buffer but every token should in any case be stored at least in a null terminated string to you are not really saving anything.

Comment: The problem with strtok is that its signature is: char* strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters); This means that I would have to strcpy my const char* string into another buffer before I can use strtok on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal, my code is structured and use a global variable `pos`(I know global variable are a bad practice but is only to give you the idea), you can replace it with a data member if you need OOP.

```
int position, messageLength;
char token[MAX]; // MAX = Value greater than the maximum length
                 // of the tokens(e.g. 1,000);


bool hasNext()
{
  return position < messageLength;
}

char* next(const char* message)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (position < messageLength && message[position] != ',') {
    token[i++] = message[position];
    position++;
  }

  position++; // ',' found

  token[i] = '\0';
  return token;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char* msg = "fred,jim,345,7665";
  position = 0;
  messageLength = strlen(msg);

  while (hasNext())
    cout << next(msg) << endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: ?? I see the `C++` tag in the question. Or what do you mean?

Comment: The benifit over my code, is that the token is not limited in size.  The flaw is that the token is dynamically sized, so heaped for each additional character.  Oh and the strlen is not free, the code walks the source 10 times for the 4 tokens.

Comment: So easy to optimize, my answer is to give the idea, not the complete solution. I've modified my code anyway.